# vb.net String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: vb.net

I have the following function called setdateformat in my VB application.

```
Public Function SetDateFormat(ByVal ArrayInputString As String) As String

   Dim FormattedDateString As String = ""
   Dim DateInput As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ArrayInputString)
   FormattedDateString = DateInput.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   Return FormattedDateString

End Function
```

Its purpose is to format the date, however it keep falling over at the line `Dim DateInput As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ArrayInputString)`. I have tried looking around online and investigating but to no avail. I have tried using dateTime.ParseExact but no luck.

Im really struggling to understand why this error is occurring for me to be honest, Hence the reason for this post so any help is much appreciated.

I have debugged the solution but to help anyone reading this understand the following values are being passed in the variables

ArrayInputString = 21/05/2015 09:29:41

Date Time Now = 05/21/2015 09:29:41

Any assistance wil be gladly taken on board

Paul

Comment: Why do you name a `String` "ArrayInputString"?

Comment: This is because the string that is coming into the function is contained in an array as follows

(0) = 0
(1) = 21/05/2015 09:29:41
(2) = 21/05/2016 09:29:41

Array input string will take index 1, deal with that then move to index 2

Comment: The method should not care about the array,  a method should be reusable. You could use it with whatever string you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` has a special meaning and functionality when it comes to date parsing: it means "replace me with the real date separator of the current culture". So i guess that your real date separator is something different like `.` or `-`.

If you look at the debugger it always uses invariant culture and not your curent culture which explains why you see dates like `5/21/2015 11:39:26 AM`.

You could try multiple approaches:

```
Public Function SetDateFormat(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    Dim DateInput As DateTime
    Dim allowedCultures = {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture}
    For Each culture In allowedCultures
        If Date.TryParse(inputString, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, DateInput) Then
            Return DateInput.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        End If
    Next
    ' try ParseExact:
    Dim formats = {"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
    If Date.TryParseExact(inputString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, DateInput) Then
        Return DateInput.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Documentation: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you so much you code seems to do the trick but i had to change the the arrays to as follows

 Dim allowedCultures As CultureInfo() = {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture} 

and im formats As String() = {"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}

Comment: @Paul: i'm glad to hear that it helped. But i don't understand the differnce between your changes and my code.

Comment: Hi Tim, without adding As CultureInfo() after Dim allowed cultures i get a compile error (blue squiggly line) saying Array initializers are valid only for arrays, but the type of allowedCultures is Object. Can you explain?

Comment: @Paul: maybe you have not `Option Infer` set to `On` (which i recommend).

Comment: maybe that is the case, this is an old solution that im fixing a bug on. so unsure whether this option is set. Is there an issue with the additonal code that i have added? Apologies my vb knowledge is not great. Thanks

Comment: @Paul: no, absolutely fine.

Comment: Awesome mate! youve changed my day. Been on that a few days now in total :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap ArrayInputString in #'s and Dim the DateInput as date before turning it into FormattedDateString.

```
Dim DateInput As Date = CDate("#" & ArrayInputString & "#")
FormattedDateString = DateInput.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```